# Infinitive scrolling of child elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way i can make the scrolling continue from the first box instead of ending at the 8th box?

Or making overflow hidden and adding one button each at the left and right which will make the slide continue from the first box after reaching the 8th box?

```css
.slide-container{
  display: flex;
  width: max-content;  
}
.box{
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-container">
<div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
  <div class="box">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is essentially carousel behavior. You might look at some of the carousel libraries or roll your own.

Comment: Here you go: https://css-tricks.com/css-only-carousel/